# Adobe Reader does not display dsfont symbols in XeLaTeX document

Tags: fonts, xetex, viewers, blackboard, adobe

When I compile the following simple document with `XeLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dsfont}

\begin{document}
    $\mathds N \subset \mathds Z \subset \mathds Q \subset \mathds R \subset \mathds C$
\end{document}
```

Adobe Reader (now version 10.1.3 but this problem existed for some time) does not display the double stroke symbols correctly. Instead it just gives an error message:

> Cannot extract the embedded font 'RAXAIQ+dsrom10'. Some characters may
>   not display or print correctly.

and replaces those symbols with a dot:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

Other readers like FoxIt or Okular have no problems displaying the document correctly.

After reading egregs comment, I looked into `dsrom10.pfb`. The easiest way for me to inspect it, is using `fontforge`. First, `fontforge` reads the font without problems. But when I try to recreate the `pfb` file, I get an error for every glyph:

> Missing Points at Extrema

I read that it is possible to correct these with `fontforge`, but then the `dsrom10.pfb` was automatically generated by `pktrace`. So even if that would work (maybe I'll try it), it cannot be the final solution.

Comment: True: I see this with Adobe Reader on both Windows and OS X, but get the correct result with Preview and TeXworks. However, I'm not sure what can be said: probably a bug in Reader.

Comment: That said, the problem only occurs with XeTeX: compiling with pdfTeX or LuaTeX gives the correct result. Perhaps an issue in XeTeX.

Comment: Either `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or `pdflatex` can produce the correct result. But `xelatex` cannot.

Comment: I got [an error message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qad7F.png) when opening the `xelatex`'s PDF output.

Comment: @JosephWright I'm inclined towards a bug in `dsrom10.pfb`, but I've no particular reason. If I use `xdv2pdf` instead of `xdvipdfmx` I get some warnings, but the result is shown correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Egreg's guess was correct. But I would not call it a bug; rather an incompatibility between `dsrom10.pfb` and `Adobe Reader`, as `FontForge` had no problems loading it. (While for the other `pdf` viewers I can not say – maybe they are just ignoring the issue.)

What I did, was to first apply the `add extrema` tool of `FontForge` and replace my version of `dsrom10.pfb` with the newly exported one. Et voilà. `Adobe Reader` does not issue an error any more and displays the symbols correctly.

As the `pfb` file was created from the `MetaFont`, this could of course not be the final solution. So after finding the tool `pktrace` — which is now called [`mftrace`](http://lilypond.org/mftrace/) — I could just recreate all the `pfb` files of `dsfont`. It seems this current version of the tool does a good enough job, as those files worked without any further intervention.

I hope I can reach the package maintainer of `dsfont` to get the correct fonts published.